# how to use render inside the for loop for node.js and ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

Inside node.js file:

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    datas.forEach( function(data){
        let txt = data.text;
        let txtarea = data.content

        res.render("home", {
            para: homeStartingContent,
            docs: data,
            textin: txt,
            textareain: txtarea 
        });
    });
});
```

In ejs file:

```php
<h1> <%= textin %> </h1>
<p> <%= textareain %> </p>
```

Comment: you want to render till the end of loop??

Comment: yes is want to render till the end of loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EJS render is a function that can only be executed only once like you cannot sent user multiple pages until the end of the loop.

In short words render can be called at once to any request whether it is post request or get request.

Hope you understood.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
datas.forEach( function(data){

    let txt = data.text;
    let txtarea = data.content
   if(txt === "Hello"){
    res.render("home", {
        para: homeStartingContent,
        docs: data,
        textin: txt,
        textareain: txtarea 
    });
}
   });
});
```